# Possible to add "Even/Odd Classes" to image attachments via wp_get_attachment_image?

Tags: attachments, images

Im looking for a way to add an alternating even/odd class directly to each image attachment when its outputted via my function below:

```
<?php
function nongallery_img_slide( $post_id = null ) {
    if ( $post_id == null ) return;
    $images = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            //'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id )
        )
    );
    if ( count( $images ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'photogallery-img' );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Can this be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image/) has a fourth parameter for custom attributes. Use it:

```
if ( count( $images ) > 0 ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( 
            $image->ID, 
            'photogallery-img',
            FALSE,
            array (
                'class' => 'attachment-photogallery-img ' 
                . ( ( $i++ % 2 === 0 ) ? 'even' : 'odd' )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap, I didnt even know it existed!..I will try this. Thanks for the quick response! Wow...so many possibilities now. Thanks so much.

Comment: May I ask, is there a way to limit this array to only being applied to images when there is more than 1? -- that way, if I were to say only add one image to a post the "even/odd" classes would not be applied?

Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Brown `count( $images ) > 1`.

Comment: Hi @toscho, thanks for the response...changing the count to 1 seems to completely eliminate any images from showing up all together when there is ONLY 1 in the post now. I still want to be able to use the function to pull ALL attachments in, but rather apply "even/odd classes" to only images uploaded in "twos" (ie. pairs), if that makes any sense?...Thanks again for the help.